# How to structure a big application in React Redux that consumes a REST API?

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've looked into consuming APIs in Redux using the redux-thunk middleware. I understand the flow of calling an API from Redux, and I understand how to structure a slice of my state to reflect the status of an API call, i.e. fetching, success, or fail. What I'd like to know now is: how do I structure a very large application to avoid boilerplate code? From what I gathered reading the docs, a single API call requires:

1. Action creators to dispatch an `API_CALL_FETCHING` action and an `API_CALL_SUCCESS` action or an `API_CALL_FAIL` action
2. Reducer code to handle each of the actions
3. A slice of your state dedicated towards reflecting the status of your API calls

Assuming I have a resource that allows basic CRUD operations on it, naively that means I should write 12 different actions (4 crud operations * 3 API status actions per call). Now imagine I have many resources that allow CRUD operations, and this starts to get huge.

Is there any eloquent way to condense the code necessary to make many API calls? Or does having a large application simply demand lots of repetition in this area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There's numerous ways to abstract the process of making API calls, and dozens of existing libraries to help with that.

Generically speaking, you can write "factory functions" that take some set of parameters (API endpoints, data descriptions, etc), and return a set of actions, reducers, and other logic for actually making the API calls and handling the data.

For existing examples, see the [Action/Reducer Generators#Network Requests](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/action-reducer-generators.md#network-requests-and-apis) and [Entity/Collection Management](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/entity-collection-management.md) sections of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links).  There's also some more intentional abstraction layers on top of Redux, like [redux-tiles](https://github.com/Bloomca/redux-tiles) and [Kea](https://kea.js.org/).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there's a looooot of tooling around this. What are some of the tools you've gotten a good amount of mileage out of?

Comment: I actually haven't used any of the tools in those categories :)  My app's needs are pretty specific. I'm a big fan of Redux-ORM for managing relational data inside of the store (which I talk about in my ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux) ), but I haven't needed to use much beyond that. Obviously other people have different use cases than me, which is why all these addons exist :)

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at Redux-ORM. I started looking at your blog posts, and they seem like great tutorials! I got a good sense of how to structure reusable middleware to process API requests by looking at the Redux real world example. But unfortunately, it doesn't go further than just GETing data and normalizing it in the state tree. Redux ORM looks like it could help with posting, putting, and deleting.

Comment: Redux-ORM is only for client-side manipulation, and doesn't do anything about API calls.  The addons categories I linked earlier do contain a bunch of addons that manage the requesting process.  Not sure how feasible it is to use Redux-ORM with any of the other tools, though.